# How to change the name of package apk installer in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I change my app name from AndroidManifest.xml
but I want change name of package installer.

How can I change "app-release" to anything I want?

How to change app-release?

[image: 1]

I change my app name from AndroidManifest.xml, but I can't change name of package installer

Comment: I'm not sure if possible within flutter but you can just manually rename it. Or make some kind of build script that does both the flutter build and the rename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mainly a question about Android build, not flutter. To change the output file name you can add this code into `android/app/bundle.gradle`

```
android {
    // ...

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all {
            outputFileName = "yourname.apk"
        }
    }
}
```

Even when you run the command `flutter build apk` you will see the wrong name in the output (I guess that's a flutter issue), but no worries, your file name will be correct:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it. Change your android **build.gradle** like below:

```
android {
   project.ext.set("appName", "my-app-name")

   defaultConfig {
       ... 
       setProperty("archivesBaseName", "$appName-$versionName-$versionCode")
    }
}
```

Note the resulted build file will be located under: **\build\app\outputs\apk\release**  instead of **\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk**